# IPA size is very large if created using build.gradle script

Tags: ios, swift, gradle, build.gradle, xcode8.2

I am creating .ipa using build.gradle script but it's creating very large IPA file because it includes SwiftSupport folder in that IPA. How to avoid including SwiftSupport in IPA using build.gradle script? Is there any parameter need to set for xcodebuild task?

Here is my xcodebuild task:

```
xcodebuild {
scheme = 'Test'
configuration='Release'
target = 'Test'
ipaFileName = "Test"
simulator = false
signing {
identity = 'iPhone Developer'
certificateURI = new File('/Volumes/Data/Certificates.p12').toURI()
certificatePassword = 'password'
   mobileProvisionURI = new File('/Volumes/Data/d333d442bfd3.mobileprovision').toURI()
}
}
```

Comment: What does your build.gradle script look like?

Comment: @srayhunter I have updated above question

Comment: You can't prevent the SwiftSupport library to be included if you use Swift.